# Wrong value being sent in form with multiple submits

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

Here is some of the form I have, with 3 submit buttons

```
<input type="image" name="submit" value="saveasset" class="submit" src="<?=BASE_URL . '/' . IMAGE_URL . '/buttons/btn_save_changes.gif'?>" />
<input type="image" name="submit" value="savetemplate" onclick="saveTemplate(); return false;" class="add_new_link" src="<?=BASE_URL . '/' . IMAGE_URL . '/buttons/btn_new_template.gif'?>"/>
<input type="image" name="submit" value="updatetemplate" onclick="saveTemplate(); return false;" class="add_new_link" src="<?=BASE_URL . '/' . IMAGE_URL . '/buttons/btn_update_template.gif'?>"/>
```

When I click the first one, it correctly submits 'saveasset' to the action function.
When I click the second one, it submits 'updatetemplate' to the action function (via AJAX), even though the button clicked is 'savetemplate'.
When I click the third one, it correctly submits 'updatetemplate' to the action function (via AJAX).

This is the saveTemplate() function (uses prototype)

```
function saveTemplate(){
    $('add_asset').request({
        onComplete: function (response) {
            $('message_inline').show();
            $('message_inline').update(response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

If I only have 2 buttons everything works as I would expect, but I need 3.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer if there is no correspondent JS code in the question?

Comment: savetemplate is called for the 2nd and 3rd submit buttons. How do you identify which is which?

Comment: +1 @zerkms, my guess is to add an `id` to the buttons, then have `savetemplate()` pass the `id`

Comment: that makes sense.. but right now the saveTemplate function isn't specifically passing anything but is passing the value of the input that it decides to use and I'm not sure where it's picking that up from.

Comment: @Damon submit buttons are somewhat special, if you have multiple `type=submit` on your page, it will always do whatever the first submit in code says. Hence why you need it to look what button you actually want

Comment: I read a number of places that it was determined by the 'value' and this seemed to be happening, but perhaps the javascript I have pulls the value from the last submit button for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing in a value to your saveTemplate() function, and tell the function to behave differently depending on the value passed in.

```
<input type="image" name="submit" value="savetemplate" onclick="saveTemplate('savetemplate'); return false;" class="add_new_link" src="<?=BASE_URL . '/' . IMAGE_URL . '/buttons/btn_new_template.gif'?>"/>
<input type="image" name="submit" value="updatetemplate" onclick="saveTemplate('updatetemplate'); return false;" class="add_new_link" src="<?=BASE_URL . '/' . IMAGE_URL . '/buttons/btn_update_template.gif'?>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks this was the best option. I changed my saveTemplate function to: 
`function saveTemplate(action){
     $('add_asset').request({
      method: 'post',
      parameters: { submit: action},
      onComplete: function (response) {
       $('message_inline').show();
           $('message_inline').update(response.responseText);
  }
     });
    }`